# Scifi short story where all citizens are armed (golden age)?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, weapon, politics, society

Trying to identify a scifi short story, possibly from the golden age, where all citizens carry sidearm weapons. Everyone is super-polite because it is legal and accepted to challenge another citizen to a duel to the death at any perceived slight or unresolvable dispute. Anyone not carrying a sidearm (e.g. children, the elderly, infirm, pacifists etc.) not therefore being able to defend themselves have to defer utterly to true citizens.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is it called the United States of America?

Comment: @thegreatjedi :: *hears crickets chirping in the distance* ::

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226530/a-perfect-backscratch-as-evidence-of-telepathy (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 33):

It's a novel rather than a short story, but that sounds exactly like [Beyond this Horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_This_Horizon) by Robert Heinlein.

> The novel depicts a world where genetic selection for increased health, longevity, and intelligence has become so widespread that the unmodified 'control naturals' are a carefully managed and protected minority. Dueling and the carrying of arms is a socially accepted way of maintaining civility in public; a man can wear distinctive clothing to show his unwillingness to duel, but this results in a lower social status.

This novel is also the source of the quote "An armed society is a polite society"

Comment: Heinlein has several novels taking place in this world, for example "I will fear no evil"

Comment: @BarafuAlbino: No, "I Will Fear No Evil" is not set in the same universe as Beyond this Horizon.

Comment: Possibly. But has the same society organization and that is what matters in this case.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino & Ben Crowell "Number of the Beast" has references to this as well if I remember correctly. It is been many years since I read that one... I could be wrong.

Comment: *The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress*, also by Heinlein, has overtones of this also: tossing someone out an airlock for being rude is not unknown in the moon, and there are no codified laws, so "mob rule" has a similar effect to everyone being armed (in the story).

Answer (score 3):

L. Neil Smith has a book called "The Probability Broach".  In it, a parallel Earth that's a libertarian utopia works the way you describe.